# Apache Spark remote cluster on JupyterHub notebooks on k8s

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I have :

Apache Spark : 2.4.4

JupyterHub : 1.1.0

Helm chart version : 0.9.0

K8S : 1.15

I build Jupyterhub on k8s with the official doc : https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/

I use official Spark image to do some local jobs : jupyter/all-spark-notebook:latest

Spark works well in local mode.

But I want to use JupyterHub notebook to do some jobs on remote (homemade) Apache Spark cluster (with K8s as orchestrator).

I already tried Apache Zeppelin, it's works well ! but I want to do the same thing with Jupyterhub.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your pain.
I burn a lot of time to create spark cluster + jupyter server work.

Try use my [docker-compose.yaml](https://github.com/ozlevka/docker-spark/blob/spark-2.4.5-cluster-with-jupiter/docker-compose.yml).

```
docker-compose up -d
```

For get jupyter token run:

```
docker-compose logs jupyter
```

Copy url starting 127.0.0.1 include token and put into your browser. Change port to 7777.

You will see empty jupyter page.
Create new notebook and run cell as you see on picture [image: new notebook with spark shell]

Enjoy using jupyter with spark...

Hope it's help you.

Comment: Very interesting but unfortunately does not help me to resolve my issue :( . At least docker-compose integration is quite easy